# jboss username and password for login

Tags: jboss

How can, we know the jboss username and password for login

Answer (score 4):

Under your JBoss application server directory, look for a file named:

```
conf/login-config.xml
```

There will be a block called:

```
<application-policy name="jmx-console">
```

... which will tell where your file-based `username=password` combinations are stored. I believe the default path is:

```
conf/props/jmx-console-users.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

By default credential in Jboss is  Given below

```
        login: admin
      password: admin
```

But if you use EAP these credential are turn off by default and there is no active user (security reasons :)). If you want to turn on these user you have to edit file in your current profile: ./deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/WEB-INF/classes/web-console-users.properties. It should be enough to remove # sign form the line with the user.

If you want to create new user don't forget to set up correct groups in

```
             web-console-roles.properties file.
```

You can easly find information where these information are store. Just open the ./conf/login-config.xml file and find the proper security domain definition. In case of Web Console application it will be web-console policy.
                     or

in JBoss application server directory you have to look for a file named which is given below:

```
                    conf/login-config.xml
```

Inside this file search for application and go to below tags

```
         <application-policy name="jmx-console">
```

which will tell where your file-based username=password combinations are stored. I think that default path is:

conf/props/jmx-console-users.properties

Answer (score 0):

User: jboss
Password: passw0rd

If you are referring to JBoss' console user/password.

Comment: I am using JBossAS4.
USER:jboss
password:password
not worked.
give me proper suggesition.

Comment: If you have read carefully (or copy+pasted what I've written) you would have used *passw0rd* (the default password in JBoss installation) instead of *password*.